# Raspberry Pi4 does not show up on wifi networki

Tags: wifi

i just bought a pi4 and try to do a headless setup (without monitor, keyboard or mousse). The issue I am heaving is that I don`t see it on the home network after I connect it to the router. I tried to use ethernet connection both to the pi and to the computer - still nothing. This way I cannot figure out the IP address to continue the setup.

Is there anyone who came through the same issue and could help with advice?

Best regards,
Tibor

Comment: What OS are you using on the Pi, what process have you followed to get to this point? Depending on your network setup (and the OS you're using) you might get away with using raspberrypi.local to connect rather than an IP address.

Comment: Look at your router's DHCP leases - is the RPi in there? If so, the lease table will show you the IP address it assigned. If it's not in there, then you've done something wrong in your setup.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure a headless setup is possible at first boot?

When I installed my Pis I had to configure the Raspbian installs on 1st boot.

After the Pi is set up, you can activate `ssh` in the config windows, after this you can remote connect to it using `ssh` and you will be in headless mode.

Answer (score 0):

You should connect the LAN cable to your router, not your PC. Once done go to your router admin page to find the pi device IP.

Even with LAN IP, I dont think it's possible to go headless at first boot because to access the pi remotely, it's either via VNC or SSH which requires you to run commands via Raspbian UI/ terminal.